# Spliting text as key value pairs of array

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have a text as below

> Questions no.1
>   this is question no.1 ans
>
> question no.2
>   this is question no.2 ans
>
> question no.3
>   this is question no.3 ans

I want to keep these question and answer in an array with key value pair i.e.

```
$array  = array(
                'question no.1' => 'this is question no.1 ans'  
                 'question no.2' => 'this is question no.2 ans'
                 'question no.3' => 'this is question no.3 ans'
               );
```

What i have tried  .

I just keep $# at end of question and $? and end of each answer so that i can explode the text into two array and can combine two array as below .

> Questions no.1 $#
>
> this is question no.1 ans ?$?
>
> question no.2 $#
>
> this is question no.2 ans $?
>
> question no.3 $#
>
> this is question no.3 ans $?

```
$questions = explode('$#',$textfromdb);
$answer = explode('$?',$textfromdb);

$combines = array_combine($questions,$answer);
```

Any suggestion are appreciated .

Thank you

Comment: why not read lines one by one from the text and keep filling the array? whats the problem?

Comment: Actually, the data comes from database as whole text. So, i need to split the text into the array .

Comment: can you show how these details stored in database?

Comment: There needs to be a compulsive empty line, if you were to distinguish between two sets of QnA. Is it so. Also, the answers if long should not have any empty line within the answer as well.Then we may read line by line until encounter an empty line.

Comment: simple store json_encode the php array and store it in db as TEXT. when reading, simple json_decode the text which shall give you the php array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions and answers are stored as a string. So, we need to [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) them when a new line (\n) appears.

[array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is used to filter out the blank values in array. [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) takes out the values only with the keys as 0, 1, 2...

Next, we need to loop through this `$filteredArray`. If you try `print_r($filteredArray)`, you'll find that the even keys contain questions and odd keys contain answers. So, we store the questions and answers accordingly.

In the end, we use [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to form key-value pairs of questions and answers.

```
 $array = explode("\n", $string);  // Explode the string when new line appears 
 $filteredArray = array_values(array_filter($array)); // Filtering out blank values and storing the values in $filteredArray 
 foreach ($filteredArray as $k => $arr) {
    if ($k %2 == 0) {             // Even keys 0, 2, 4... contain the questions
        $questions[] = $arr;
    } else {                      // Odd keys 1, 3, 5... contain the answers
        $answers[] = $arr;
    }
 }

$questionAnswers = array_combine($questions, $answers); // Converting questions-answers as key-value pairs
```

Answer (score 0):

**array_combine()** — Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values

**Syntax:**

```
array_combine ( array $keys , array $values );
```

Creates an array by using the values from the keys array as keys and the values from the values array as the corresponding values.

Try keeping Question as a Separate Array and answer as a Separate Array

```
<?php
// Question Array
$question = array('Question1','Question2','Question3');
//Answer Array
$answer = array('Answer1','Answer2','Answer3');
//array_combine()
$combined_array = array_combine($question, $answer);
print_r($combined_array);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [Question1] => Answer1 [Question2] => Answer2 [Question3] => Answer3 )
```

Comment: that is what i actually want to do but from text. Please check the things that i have tried .